# Can I filter this delegate to check if any name is repeated and remove

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this delegate:

```
   private static readonly Func<GetAddress, GetNames> ConvertAddress = a => new Address() {
        StreetNumber = a.streetNumber,
        City = a.city,
        State = a.state,
        zip = a.zip,
        firstName = a.firstName,
        LastName = a.lastName 
    };
```

I call it like this:

```
ADRESS = o.Addresses.Select(ConvertAddress).First(), ...
```

so I want some sort of filter for first name and last name. If they were used once I want those null the next time it is called.  Not the address to null, but just the name.

so if john johnson is going through this twice I want the second time john johnson goes through this to have his name assigned to "" or null.

Comment: In this context, what is o, and what is Addresses.  Can you add the code for that?

Comment: It's generally bad idea to write queries that mutate the underlying collection that they're querying.  It results in confusing programs that are very hard to work with.

Comment: @Ryios `Addresses` is an `IEnumerable<GetAddress>`.  That's obvious from the code provided.

Comment: o is a soap object .. and as above Addresses is an ienumerable of get address.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you need some kind of state to be shared between each instance of the call. The cleanest way to do this would be to pass it in so your function would change to look something like:

```
private static readonly Func<GetAddress, ISet<string>, GetNames> ConvertAddress = a, usedNames => 
{ 
var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstName, a.LastName);
var fullNameHasBeenUsed = usedNames.Contains(fullName);
usedNames.Add(fullName);
return new Address() {
    StreetNumber = a.streetNumber,
    City = a.city,
    State = a.state,
    zip = a.zip,
    firstName = fullNameHasBeenUsed ? null : a.firstName,
    LastName = fullNameHasBeenUsed ? null : a.lastName 
};}
```

And then you would call it like :

```
var usedFirstNames = new HashSet<string>();
ADRESS = o.Addresses.Select(a => ConvertAddress(a, usedFirstNames)).First()
```